# Auto import and import suggestions in IntelliJ / WebStorm

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, import, webstorm

I have implemented a barrel in a folder in an angular 5 typescript project.

I essentially export some classes ie.
`export { TooBigClassNameToWorkWith as EasierClassName } from @app/models` 
which is in another folder completely.

After doing this, I don't get autocompleted imports nor import suggestions.

I get correct auto imports and suggestions in vscode.

So my question is: 
**Is there something I'm missing to get better support for this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a bug, please follow [WEB-31681](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-31681) for updates